# Как правильно подключить скрипты и стили в дочернюю тему wordpress?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Всем привет! Хочу в дочернюю тему wordpress подключить стили скрипты в файл functions.php

```html
<?php

// enqueue the child theme stylesheet

Function wp_schools_enqueue_scripts() {
wp_register_style( 'childstyle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css'  );
wp_enqueue_style( 'childstyle' );
wp_register_style( 'animatestyle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/animate.css'  );
wp_enqueue_style( 'animatestyle' );
wp_register_style( 'ioniconsstyle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/ionicons.min.css'  );
wp_enqueue_style( 'ioniconsstyle' );
}
function my_scripts_method(){
 wp_enqueue_script( 'newscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/script.js');
 wp_enqueue_script( 'candyplugins', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/candy-plugins.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_schools_enqueue_scripts', 11);
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
?>
```

Пытаюсь подключить скрипты и стили в wordpress. Стили подключаются норм, а скрипты не работают..(( Где косяк?

Comment: Скрипты сами подключились или нет? Т.е. ошибка в js или в том, что самих скриптов нет?

Comment: скрипты подключились(можно в функции указывать сразу 2 скрипта под одним именем? и то, что хук у стилей и скриптов одинаковый wp_enqueue_scripts - это нормально или нужно как-то делать по другому?), в коде страницы отображаются, но я не знаю правильно ли подключены и не кофликтуют ли с чем, потому что сам функционал не работает.. гугл конкретно на мой пример ответ не дает

Comment: Под одним именем - нет. Вообще это нужно без хуков выполнять, сразу в functions.php. Откройте консоль (F12), посмотрите, на что жалуется.

Comment: добавил в впереди в скрипте 
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
заработало! :)